# Is scala sufficient for native, system and kernel programming?

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, native, kernel, systems-programming

1. Is there a compiler that translates Scala code to native code?

   - Is there a released compiler?
   - Is there a compiler under development?
   - If there is no such compiler, would it be possible to write one?

     - If it is not possible: What are the reasons for that?
2. Is Scala sufficient for system programming?
3. Is Scala sufficient for kernel programming (e.g. programming a device driver)?
4. If Scala is not sufficient for system or kernel programming: What are the reasons for that?

I know Scala has been targeted to the Java platform. As far as I know Scala also fits to .Net / C# intermediate code thing. IMHO Java and .Net platforms are relatively similar, this is no surprise.

Java and .Net platforms deliver services or some kind of infrastructure which may be missing in system and kernel development.

1. Which features of the Java platform are essential or necessary for Scala which are missing in system / kernel development?
2. Which of these features / requirements could possibly be covered by integrating existing solutions into system / kernel development or by future development?

Comment: Effectively, the answer is "Good grief, no."  Scala (and Java, for that matter) is a high-level language intended to abstract away lots of annoying details like what hardware you have and how to handle memory.  In kernel etc. programming, all you care about is those annoying details.  Use a tool designed for the job!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is have a look at scala LLVM: http://greedy.github.com/scala-llvm/
It is under development. Some issues like garbage collection remain.

For more details and insights have a look at one of the relevant mailing list discussions:
http://groups.google.com/group/scala-debate/browse_thread/thread/4ce486843cf7ef33/01ac59db9d8c5137?lnk=gst&q=LLVM+#01ac59db9d8c5137

You may also take a look at the rust programming language

Comment: Under development doesnt mean: get commits every day. Plus it's a single person effort so you better start helping or stop complaining ;)

Comment: Not complaining. Just state a fact.

Comment: There is now [Scala Native](https://github.com/scala-native/scala-native).  Given that it is still GC'ed, I would not see it suitable for kernel and systems programming.